# Proving that $ f'(0)=0$ with $ f(x)={g(x)\cos(1/x^3) ~~for~~ x≠0 , 0~~ for ~~x=0}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, derivatives

Assume that $g$ is a. differentiable function such that  $g(0)=g'(0)=0$ , $g''(0)= -2$ we let 
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
g(x)\cos\big(\frac{1}{x^3}\big),  & \text{if $x \ne 0$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $x = 0$}
\end{cases}$$

Show that $f'(0)=0$. can anyone help?

Comment: @Arthur I tried to use the definition of derivative. didn't get to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|\cos(a)|\le 1$ and $g'(0)=g(0)=0$ by definition of derivative  we have

$$\bigg|\frac{g(x)\cos(1/x^3)}{x}\bigg|\le \bigg|\frac{g(x)}{x}\bigg| = \bigg|\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}\bigg|\to \left|g'(0)\right|=0~~~as ~~x\to0$$

Hence by definition  derivative $$\color{red}{f'(0) = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}= \lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x)\cos(1/x^3)}{x} =0}$$

Comment: Thanks for the edit and answer! What was the use of the given value of g''? @GuyFsone

Comment: read your exercise sheet it might be useful int the sequels not here